# xamppをインストールしたけど、xamppのフォルダが出てこない

Tags: xampp, mamp

iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013)にXAMPP-VM / PHP 7.2.8をインストールしましたが、xamppのファルダが通常なら出ますよね？
xamppフォルダがないけど、lamppというフォルダが出ます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

xamppのコントロールパネルは出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

lamppの中のhttps.conf)(9行のみ)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なんどもインストールし直してもxamppフォルダが出来てませんし、 
インストーラーをクリックしてもセットアップウィザードが出ません。 
どうしてでしょうか。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: ディレクトリがlamppになっていてなにか困ることでもあるでしょうか？

Comment: VM用でインストールしてました。インストールし直したら、xamppのフォルダが出てきました。中身はlamppと一緒なんですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

名前の由来

> 元々は対応OSはLinuxのみであり、その頭文字Lを付けLAMPPと称したが、後に複数のOSに対応したためLをXに変えXAMPPとなった。

https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP